# How can I find the general solution to a second order ODE when $yy''=3(y')^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I reduce $yy''=3(y')^2$ to first order and find its general solution by using $z=y'$ and $y''=\frac{dz}{dy}z$?

At first, I reduced it to a first order, and I know that I'm supposed to do separable parts. However, I can't seem to make that work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You get $zy\frac{dz}{dy}=3z^2$ after plugging in. Can you solve this for $z$ as a function of $y$?

Comment: I got that it would be $zy\frac{dz}{dy}=3z^2$ not cubed, but then i don’t know what you mean by solving z as a function of y. Could you explain why it would be cubed, if I’m wrong on that, and how I would solve it like you’re saying a little more, please?

Comment: You're right, I had a typo. Also, this is a seprapable diff eq. Get all $z$'s on one side, all $y$'s on the other, then integrate

Comment: Okay, so I did that, and I got ln(z)+C=ln(y)+C

Comment: Would that be the general solution, or is there a next step?

Comment: No, that's wrong.  What happened to the $3$?

Comment: oh sorry ln(z)+C=3ln(y)+C I forgot to add it into my typing

Comment: Once you solve for $z$ as a function of $y$ you replace $z$ with $y'$ and solve this resulting diff eq for $y$.

Comment: Oh! Okay. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That makes way more sense than what I kept ending up with.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
yy''=3(y')^2,
\end{align}
divide by $yy'$
\begin{align}
\frac{y''}{y'}=3\frac{y'}{y},
\end{align}
integrate
\begin{align}
\ln(y')=3\ln(y)+c\\
y'=cy^3.
\end{align}
Divide by $y^3$ and integrate
\begin{align}
\frac{y'}{y^3}=c\\
\frac{-1}{2y^2}=c_1x+c_2\\
y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1x+c_2}}
\end{align}